# Why does snprintf/vsnprintf open /proc/self/maps on every single call with %n?

Tags: gcc, glibc

I call (indirectly) `size_t sl; vsnprintf(ap, "...%n...", ..., &sl, ...);`, now my program opens `/proc/self/maps` on every call to `vsnprintf`. Why? And how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 4):

If `glibc` was compiled with `_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`, it checks, whether the format string used is in a writeable code segment (to prevent a class of security bugs that involve using `%n` to write to hacker controlled memory locations). Now, for this, `glibc` opens and reads `/proc/self/maps` to do the check.

Solutions:

1. Compile `glibc` without `_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`.
2. Don't use `%n` (doesn't matter whether it is in write-able or read-only memory).

Comment: I'd definitely go with option 2 (or just live with it).  `_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` is a really nice feature - one that should also be used when compiling ones own programs (IMHO).

Comment: "Compile glibc without _FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" - you probably mean "compile *your program* without _FORTIFY_SOURCE=2".

Comment: no, ```glibc``` is the code that does the open and read ```/proc/self/maps``` thing.

Comment: glibc checks a flag before performing the `%n` checks. It only performs them if the call originated from code which was compiled with source fortification enabled. Note that some toolchains try to automatically enable source foritifcation.

Comment: ``gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`` -> ``/usr/include/features.h:373:4: warning: #warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O) [-Wcpp]`` nope